# Using the Salesforce API without login using nuxt

Tags: rest-api, api

I'm new to using the Salesforce API and I'm creating a web app.

**What I'm trying to do**:
Each of my opportunities in Salesforce has a unique code,
I have a Nuxt application where the client enters a code and then it checks to see if there is an opportunity with a matching code,
If there is - it returns some specific opportunity fields that it will store in the store (Name, Opportunity Date, etc).

I haven't started developing it yet because, unlike other API's - Salesforce seems to want you to log in to access data, but these clients aren't Salesforce users. Is there anything like an API key that most other API's provide (eg; Google Firestore has an API key that you store in an ENV variable that you use).

Comment: Just create a service account for yourself (just any user with API access), store the tokens in your backend, and talk to SF API via that service account

Comment: There is no way of accessing it without paying an extra $150 a month for another user?

Comment: depending on APIs you actually need you may be able to make do with a Salesforce Platform license which is some $35 per month. Also, if you have ANY user, you can just use that one (the best practice is to use a dedicated one so you can clearly see whether it was an automated action vs human using a computer, but it's not a technical requirement)

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce does not provide an API key store for you to be able to do these types of requests. You will need a [Conected App](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.connected_app_overview.htm&type=5), and an authentication mechanism in order to get an access token to be able to request information from Salesforce. For example, [JWT Oauth Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5).

Further more, you can integrate data to the external application using the [User Interface API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_responses_record_ui.htm)

Comment: That's not strictly speaking true. You can use your Username + password concatenated with your security token. This works without connected apps.

Comment: using username/password is not considered a best practice for any sort of server to server integration, which is why I do not mention it. yes, many sdk's and libraries support this, however, it is not a "robust" or secure way of developing integrations.

Comment: Forget SDKs. It is supported by Salesforce API itself, and OP is looking for something on the cheap-o. If he is certain of the way his secrets are stored and the networking interface (lol) then why not. Set the password policy to never expire and happy days :)

Comment: yes, indeed, however, its not something I will go into, nor recommend, regardless of cheap-o or not. Feel free to post another answer which involves a  user/pswd integration